# Error message when running .bat file to start Minecraft server, invalid maximum heap/could not create Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, server, heap-memory, minecraft, ram

While trying to create a personal Minecraft server, I'm running into the error message below when running the .bat file. I'm positive I have enough free RAM and almost positive I'm running the most up to date version of 64-bit Java. Is there anything else that could be causing this?

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx8G

The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Have you checked the output of "java -version", bc this sounds awfully like you are on a 32bit JVM to me.

Comment: @Taschi The output I'm getting is:
```java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)```

What does this mean?

Comment: A 64-bit JVM should tell you something akin to this:

    java version "9.0.1"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

So it seems like yours is 32 bits after all...

(Also, it's a bit out of date, the most recent version is Java 14: https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk14&jvmVariant=hotspot)